# Looking for best practice, articles, tests or studies on video placement on websites.

Tags: usability-study, video, quantitative-analysis

We are a publisher of many special interest (that doesn't mean x-rated! ;) news websites (tech, music, sport etc). The majority of our content is editorial but we obviously have a growing amount of video content.

I am looking for any information on the placement of video-based news content. e.g, how the other newsstand publications/major corporations came to their conclusions, What they found to be most successful in terms of viewing times and plays, sizes, thumbnails, sidebar vs main column, left right, anything with a touch of quantitative results would be best.

If you know of a paper or study, even a blog post i'd be happy to read it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This article might be interest to you [A manual for effective online video placement](http://www.imediaconnection.com/content/32379.asp)

To quote the aspects of the article which might be interesting to you :

> **On-page video placement**
>
> **Front and center**: Video can be the most engaging online asset you have, so make sure consumers see it and view it. The video should be
>   visible when the page loads. Placing videos below the fold and
>   requiring consumers to scroll down will not offer any benefits to your
>   brand or to the consumer. In addition, the call-to-action should be
>   prominent, such as "Click here to view a video about..." or a "Play"
>   button displayed.
>
> **Maximize the play experience**: Videos should play embedded on the web page or in a lightbox player. The method that you choose depends
>   on the type of video, target audience, and desired action. A lightbox
>   approach guarantees that viewers are focused only on the video by
>   opening a layer on top of the page that plays the video, such as the
>   Tiger Direct product video featured below. That said, the layer will
>   block access to everything else on the page, so multitaskers may not
>   appreciate this approach.

With regards,to the length of  videos you should be looking at, I recommend looking at [this article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/tjwalker/2012/01/26/how-long-should-an-internet-video-be-media-training/) .To quote the article :

> The rule of thumb I try to follow when creating internet videos is
>   this: stick to one idea, one topic and one main point, and say it as
>   briefly as possible without leaving out all of your good stuff.
>   Personally, I find than most of my daily news commentary videos are
>   between 60 to 90 seconds with some occasionally going to 2 or even
>   three minutes.
>
> Also remember that you don’t have to shoot for exact, precise times
>   like 30 or 60 seconds. Those exact times mattered in traditional
>   linear broadcast venues where everything is scheduled and programmed
>   around a set grid. But social media and internet video isn’t like
>   that, so take a little more time or a little less time if that’s what
>   you need. If you’ve got a great message, you might be able to say
>   everything you need to in 9 seconds. But if you’ve produced a
>   world-class documentary that’s 3 hours long, you might be able to get
>   a huge internet audience for that too.
>
> Another option is to break up our videos into part 1, part 2, etc.
>   This way people can take bite sizes without ever feeling impatient.
>   There is a certain psychology involved with your viewers. If you make
>   your videos consistently interesting and consistently short, then you
>   always are leaving them wanting more. However, if your viewers are
>   consistently dumping out of your videos before they finish, you are
>   conditioning them to turn you off and to make judgments that you may
>   be boring them. All things being equal, it’s better not to do that, so
>   err on the side of being just long enough to be really interesting and
>   not one second linger.